# Не работает вход с помощью vk_api

Tags: python-3.x

```
config = {}
with open("config.py") as file:
onstring = file.read().split("\n")[:-1]
config = dict()
for item in onstring:
    key = item.split(" ")[0]
    value = item.split(" ")[1:]
    config[key] = value

vk = vk_api.VkApi(login = config['username'] , password = config['password'])
vk.auth()
```

Мне надо чтобы он брал логин и пароль из файла config.py и выполнял вход
Содержимое config.py:

```
username логин
password пароль
```

[Решено]

```
def write_msg(user_id, peer_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.send',{'user_id':user_id, 'peer_id':user_id, 'message':s})
```

Ошибка keyEroor : 'chat_id' при отправке сообщения в беседу:

```
peer_id = 2000000000 + int(response['chat_id'])
write_msg(item['peer_id'], ms)
```

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: @Qwerty123 Судя по виду write_msg вы передаёте ему не верное число аргументов, в коде write_msg(item['peer_id'], ms) вы передаёте 2 аргумента, а требуется 3 - user_id, peer_id, s. При этом первые два числовые а третий строка.

Comment: @Qwerty123 В response наверняка нет ключа 'chat_id', потому ошибка KeyError. Можете распечатать print(response) и посмотреть какие в нём поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате кода чтения конфига ключи читаются как строки например 'password', а вот значения читаются как список из строк например ['пароль'], причём список в котором будет несколько значений которые получились в результате разбиения пробелами. А VkApi как понимаю принимает логин и пароль как строки, а вы ему подаёте в итоге как список из строк. Причина получения значения как список в указании [1:] в строке получения значения.

Если пробелы в пароле и имени пользователя не встречаются, тогда можно вместо [1:] написать [1], это сделает значение строкой вместо списка. Если пробелы встречаются, тогда нужно разделитель другой выбрать, например писать в файле password:пароль т.е. в качестве разделителя выбрать двоеточие, тогда потом ключ и значение извлекаются просто `(key, value) = item.split(":")` и при этом оба будут строкой.

По поводу ошибки KeyEroor : 'chat_id' это означает что не найден в структуре словаря ключ 'chat_id'. У вас написано response['chat_id'], наверняка просто в нём нет такого ключа, нужно распечатать print(response) и посмотреть какие у него ключи.

Comment: и что же можно сделать?

Comment: Если пробелы в пароле и имени пользователя не встречаются, тогда можно вместо [1:] написать [1], это сделает значение строкой вместо списка. Если пробелы встречаются, тогда нужно разделитель другой выбрать, например писать в файле password:пароль  т.е. в качестве разделителя выбрать двоеточие, тогда потом ключ и значение извлекаются просто (key, value) = item.split(":")  и при этом оба будут строкой.

Comment: Всё работает, только теперь есть ещё одна ошибка. Отправка сообщения в беседу peer_id = 2000000000 + int(response['chat_id'])
                                    write_msg(item['peer_id'], ms)

Comment: @Qwerty123 Нужно знать детали, какая ошибка, компиляции или времени исполнения, если исполнения то что выдаёт ВК в ответ? Также вижу что write_msg идёт сам по себе, а по идее это должно быть вызвано как vk_api.write_msg... или vk.write_msg... зависит от того как у вас модуль называется или класс, т.е. просто голая write_msg по идее не должно работать.

Comment: есть переменная 'def write_msg(user_id, peer_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id':user_id, 'peer_id':user_id, 'message':s})' Извините не могу понять как тут код вставить

Comment: @Qwerty123 Можете весь нужный помогающий разъяснению вопроса код и дополнительные вопросы писать в своём основном вопросе, а не в комментарии здесь.

Comment: @Qwerty123 Судя по функции нужно писать write_msg(user_id, peer_id, s), т.е. три аргумента а не два, при этом похоже что первые два должны быть числовые, а третий строка.

Comment: Я забыл саму ошибку написать, извините KeyError: 'chat_id'Хотя в документации есть такое значение

Comment: @Qwerty123 KeyError означает что данный ключ ('chat_id') отсутвует в используемой структуре, т.е. если есть словарь d, и вы к нему делаете доступ по ключу d['key'], то словарь должен содержать ключ 'key' иначе будет KeyError исключение. Вы можете посмотреть какие ключи есть в словаре написав print(dict_name)  (dict_name это имя вашего словаря в котором ищите 'chat_id')

Comment: всё разобрался, спасибо)